# Cannot exec sh into Kubernetes container: reading from closed file, no space left on device

Tags: docker, kubernetes

One of the nodes in my Kubernetes v1.16.3 cluster has ended up in a strange state. The node is running Debian 10.1 and Docker 19.03.1. When I try to `kubectl exec sh` into a container on that node I see these error messages in the node's `journalctl -u docker` (the 2nd is also reported by `kubectl` itself):

```
stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo
Error running exec ... in container: failed to create runc console socket: mkdir /tmp/pty...: no space left on device ..."
```

At this point I don't see which device may have become full. A simple `df` does not raise any alarms. How can I further diagnose and remedy the situation?

BTW, the problem so far has persisted across `kubectl drain`, `systemctl restart docker`, restarting `kube-proxy` and the CNI's pod, as well as several other measures.

Comment: Can you provide some more details and output from the `df` and `kubectl describe node <node_name>`
Can you check also if you are not running out of space allocated for Docker
by removing some images and containers and then trying? You could try to use `docker system prune`.This will remove some unused data.

Comment: @HelloWorld A combination of `docker system prune` and `docker rmi $(docker images -q)` (plus waiting a bit) apparently remedied the situation. If you want to turn your comment into an answer I shall accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OP already mentioned in comments, a combination of `docker system prune` and `docker rmi $(docker images -q)` remedied the situation.